# Filtering this Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I want to use this query:

```
var queryData = from va in xdoc.Descendants("language")
                select new
                {
                    StringID = va.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id").Value,
                    Language = va.Attribute("name").Value,
                    LanguageData = va.Element("value").Value,
                };

var organizedData = from x in queryData
                    group x by x.StringID into xg
                    select new
                    {
                        StringID = xg.Key,
                        English = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == "ENGLISH_US").LanguageData,
                        Custom = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == languageBox.SelectedItem.ToString()).LanguageData,
                    };

mainView.DataSource = organizedData.ToList();
mainView.Refresh();
```

except that as an additional condition for what is retrieved for the `Custom` anonymous type, its value must be equal to `"*"`.

Why can't I figure this out? I guess I don't know enough about anonymous types or the `=>` operator.

Comment: Are the final trailing commas in the `select new {` statements valid? Guessing it's just two copy paste errors because I don't think it would compile.

Comment: It compiles fine, but they are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
mainView.DataSource = organizedData.Where(x => x.Custom == "*").ToList();
```

Comment: Amazing. Yes, thank you. The `.Where` function -- I now see its proper usage.

Comment: This works fine but it's more readable to put the Where clause right in the linq query. And that's the whole point of linq :P

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for. I put the value in a temp variable so it doesn't have to be computed twice.

```
       var organizedData = from x in queryData
                            group x by x.StringID into xg
                            let temp = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == languageBox.SelectedItem.ToString()).LanguageData
                            where temp == "*"
                            select new
                            {
                                StringID = xg.Key,
                                English = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == "ENGLISH_US").LanguageData,
                                Custom = temp,
                            };
```