# Searching a DataGridView for a match or partial match

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datagridview

Tried to sift through the google results; no luck. What I'm trying to do is, given some text in a TextBox: search for at least a partial match in any column of my DataGridView, and have the control select the first row (show it as the top row and have it highlighted) that it encounters with that partial match.

Here is my declaration of the DataSource for the DataGridView and how the columns are organized:

```
 var queryData = from va in xdoc.Descendants("language")
                    select new
                    {
                        StringID = va.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id").Value,
                        Language = va.Attribute("name").Value,
                        LanguageData = va.Element("value").Value,
                    };

        var organizedData = from x in queryData
                     group x by x.StringID into xg
                     select new
                     {
                         StringID = xg.Key,
                         English = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == "ENGLISH_US").LanguageData,
                         Custom = xg.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Language == languageBox.SelectedItem.ToString()).LanguageData,
                     };

        mainView.DataSource = organizedData.ToList();
```

And here is the current definition of the function that handles a click of the 'Search' button:

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentIndex = mainView.CurrentRow.Index;

        if (searchBox.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            mainView.CurrentCell = mainView[0,0];
            mainView.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering this Linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988865/filtering-this-linq-query)

Comment: Try to phrase your question right the first time. Spend some time on it. If not, Edit it and don't repost.

Comment: Thanks Henk, however these are two different questions. Please try to examine more closely the question being asked, as opposed to simply assuming that duplicate content across questions indicates duplicate questions.

Comment: Again, I lol because these two questions are so obviously different at even a cursory glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you close:

```
string searchForText = "whatever";

DataGridViewRow rowFound = mainView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
  .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
      .Any(cell => ((dynamic)cell.Value).StringID.Contains(searchForText)));

if (rowFound != null) {
    mainView.Rows[rowFound.Index].Selected = true;
    mainView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowFound.Index;
}
```

Comment: Hmm this does a pretty good job, however for some reason it does not go to a row in which, say, the first column contains the text. Thank you for the reply by the way!

Comment: Odd.  Is there anything special about the first column?  Is it a combobox or something different like that?

Comment: Mm, nope. It is the "StringID" anonymous type from that Linq query in the OP. Also, if possible, successive clicks of the 'Search' button should advance the selected row of the DataGridView onto the next potential candidate.

Comment: Well I've updated my answer to (hopefully) account for searching for StringId; however, having successive searches cycle through the next result, and the next one beyond that I'll leave to you.  That will be a tad bit of a pain, but it should be doable.  You'll have to keep track of whether the search term has changed, and also keep track of the most recent row found for the current search term